# R- How do I select the rows indicated in the output of the sample()?

Tags: r, assign

I want to do an exploratory factor analysis and then a confirmatory factor analysis on 415 subjects. I want to divide my sample into two more or less equal samples so that I could do the EFA on 208 subjects and the CFA on 207 subjects.

I use the `sample()` function:

```
a<-sample(1:415,208,replace=F)

sort(a)

b<-sample(1:415,207,replace=F)

sort(b)
```

And I get different values.

I want to assign a number 1 in a column "AFE.AFC" of my dataset for all the 208 participants that are mentioned in "a"  and a number 2 in the same column for the 207 participants that are mentioned in "b".

Do you know some formula that could do that?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So you don't actually want to use `sample` twice because you'll very likely get some numbers which show up in both. Assuming your data is in a dataframe called `df` you can do something like this

```
df$AFE.AFC <- 2 # this creates a column called AFE.AFC where all the values are 2
a.index <- sample(1:415, 208, replace = FALSE) # randomly samples 208 numbers from 1-415
df$AFE.AFC[a.index] <- 1 # this changes the value in the column category and changes it to 1 if it's the row number it's in is in AFE.AFC
```

The trick is in the 3rd and last line. If the numbers `5, 21, 103, 4, ...` are in `a.index` then the 5th, 21th, 103th and so fourth values of `df$AFE.AFC` will be changed from 1 to 2.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!